# Tmux, How to type the prefix key itself

Tags: tmux

I set the prefix key to backquote， I can't type a backquote in vim. when I press `, it took it as the prefix key, then nothing inserts into the editor.

How can I input a backquote in vim, when I'm under tmux. Thanks~

```
`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind a key to "send-prefix" or "send-keys '`'". Many people bind so that pressing the prefix twice sends the prefix character, for you that would be:

```
bind '`' send-keys '`'
```

Comment: I had to also execute `tmux kill-server` for the change to take effect